# SQL: Grouped Count?

Tags: mysql, sql

I ran a Christmas contest running from 1 till 24 of December. Each member could take part once a day. Now I would like to know **how often** they took part (minimum is once, maximum is 24 times).

The result should be something like this:

```
Participations | Amount of participated members
1              | 3523
2              | 329
3              | 1929
...
22             | 592
23             | 823
24             | 928
```

My table is very simple and only contains two fields: `memberid` and `solution word`. so it's not possible to group by DATE or something.

It must be something like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS participations FROM table GROUP BY memberid, ORDER BY participations ASC
```

Comment: You have an errant comma on your query. Also, how will you no which count relates to which memberid? Try again, and if you're still struggling, see: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: How do you know members didn't participate multiple times per day if you have no date?

Comment: @BenM That is explained in the question (well, your edit of the question!).

Comment: @Strawberry where?

Comment: "Each member could take part once a day" - Presumably the logic was handled in the application code.

Comment: You may find that nobody participated exactly 23 times, say, in which case there will be no result for 23. You can handle the logic of missing results like that in application code.

Comment: @MatBailie Good grief. I swear I'm losing my mind.

Answer (score 5):

```
SELECT participations, count(memberid) Members FROM
     (
     SELECT memberid, count(*) participations
     FROM table
     GROUP BY memberid
     ) x
GROUP BY participations
```

Comment: This is how I'd do it too. Note that this excludes missing results (e.g. if no one participated exactly 23 times), but I think it's best to handle issues like that in application code.